# Same commands but different output in the internal git bash of intellij idea and the external one

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, git-bash

I am configuring the environment for learning [the algorithm curriculum on coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1). For testing, I ran `java-algs4 --version` in the idea, but the output is `bash: java-algs4: command not found`. I then ran the same command outside. It works well. Why this happened?

[The question above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvK2x.png)

Another question is, why my java in windows didn't work? I can see the version info if I run `java --version`, and it works when I run `javac HelloWorld.java`, but why `java HelloWorld` doesn't work?

[It doesn't work in my windows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhrmx.png)

[It works when I use wsl.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9xBi.png)

I restarted my computer and idea, but nothing changed.

Comment: Environment may be different depending on how the app is started. Start IntelliJ IDEA from the command line per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line in the same terminal where this command works and it should also work in the IDE.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know why the second question happened. I mistakenly added an environment variable `CLASSPATH` which didn't include the current path. The default configuration of java includes the current path, but when you set a classpath, it won't check the current path unless you set it.
For the first question, I indeed start the ide in command line, which may change the env. After I deleted the CLASSPATH environment variable, and tried to start the ide straightly, the first question also disappeared.